# Cutting specific part of string using cut in bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I have a text file on a Linux machine which contains the strings:

```
appset.org 87.76.29.21 ns1.appset.org ns2.appset.org
bbchannel.eu 87.77.29.25 ns1.appset.org ns2.appset.org
cyberset.it 87.76.29.22 ns1.appset.org ns2.appset.org
cybersetsystems.com 87.76.29.21 ns1.appset.org ns2.appset.org
romelidays.com 87.98.29.21 ns1.appset.org ns2.appset.org
novaprospect.eu 87.76.29.21 ns1.appset.org ns2.appset.org
```

All I want is to remove the part starting from the IP address and get output with only website name eg `appset.org`,`bbchannel.eu`.

The code I have tried is:

```
 #!/bin/bash
  while read p; do
      echo "$p" | cut -c 1-13
   done <experiment
```

But it doesn't seem to be right. I have also tried using the `sed` command but still my logic doesn't work. I am really new to bash. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: What's wrong with simply using `${p/ */}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the right tool for the job, `cut`, but are making it far more complicated than you need. There is absolutely no reason to use a bash loop here, that just makes things slower and more complicated. `cut` will process every line in the file by itself. However, the default delimiter for `cut` is a tab, not a space, so you need to tell it to cut on spaces using the `-d` flag. Then, instead of telling it to cut specific characters, just tell it to print the first *field* with `-f 1`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f 1 file 
appset.org
bbchannel.eu
cyberset.it
cybersetsystems.com
romelidays.com
novaprospect.eu
```

With `sed`, you would try to remove everything after the first space:

```
$ sed 's/ .*//' file 
appset.org
bbchannel.eu
cyberset.it
cybersetsystems.com
romelidays.com
novaprospect.eu
```

Or, you could use `awk` which splits into fields on whitespace by default:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' file 
appset.org
bbchannel.eu
cyberset.it
cybersetsystems.com
romelidays.com
novaprospect.eu
```

Or perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\s.*//' file 
appset.org
bbchannel.eu
cyberset.it
cybersetsystems.com
romelidays.com
novaprospect.eu
```

Or perl again:

```
$ perl -lane 'print $F[0]' file 
appset.org
bbchannel.eu
cyberset.it
cybersetsystems.com
romelidays.com
novaprospect.eu
```

You could even do it in the shell, but this will be far slower for larger files and is [generally not a good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716):

```
$ while read want rest; do echo "$want"; done < file
appset.org
bbchannel.eu
cyberset.it
cybersetsystems.com
romelidays.com
novaprospect.eu
```

Or, safer for arbitrary input:

```
$ while read -r want rest; do printf '%s\n' "$want"; done < file
appset.org
bbchannel.eu
cyberset.it
cybersetsystems.com
romelidays.com
novaprospect.eu
```

Comment: With the `while read` part, you'll also want to make sure `$IFS` contains the characters you want to consider as delimiter.

Comment: @terdon   Thank you so much

Comment: @terdon ..Let me as you one more thing..How can i do this by only making change to the first line of the text.. ie 'appset.org 87.76.29.21 ns1.appset.org ns2.appset.org'. Do i have to use a loop in this case ?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, but since here the delimiter is (apparently) supposed to be a space, there didn't seem to be any reason to set it explicitly.

Comment: @AvinashBabu no, but that is a completely different question. The simplest way would be to use `head -n1` to print only the first line and pipe that to `cut` like this: `head -n1 file | cut -d' ' -f1`.